# I want to print each item from a list using a for loop but I get random numbers instead

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Using a for loop, I want to print each item in a list. So I made this code:

```
 from termcolor import colored # Ignore this and the "colored" function in the strings, just a 
                               # package I installed.
 titles = ["Dummy Story"] 

 bookshelf = {

 "Dummy Story": ["Page 1", "Page 2", "Page 3", "Page 4"] # The list I want it to print 

  } 


def readfun():

    print(colored("So you want to read a story now?", "green"))
    global titles        
    global bookshelf
    print(titles)
    storytoread = input(colored("Choose a book to read: ", "yellow"))
    for page in storytoread:
        print(page, end='')


readfun()
```

It's a sort of story reading project I'm making. The `storytoread` variable stores the name of the book the user wants to read. All info is from the dictionary called `bookshelf`. I'd expect it to print the list value's items since the value of the `storytoread` variable will be identified as a key of a key-value pair from the dictionary `bookshelf`.  However, all it does is print the string stored in `storytoread`, not the ones I want it to print. How do I make it do this?

Comment: You know your books are in book shelf. Have you gone to book shelf and searched for your book?

Comment: Well, you can see in the titles that "Dummy Story" is available. So I'd expect it to be the only book the user can read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using single variable `BOOKSHELF` containing all information about your books. Also you don't need to use `global`:

```
from termcolor import colored

BOOKSHELF = {'Dummy Story': ['Page 1', 'Page 2', 'Page 3', 'Page 4']}

def read_fun():

    print(colored('So you want to read a story now?', 'green'))
    print(list(BOOKSHELF.keys()))
    story_to_read = input(colored('Choose a book to read: ', 'yellow'))
    if story_to_read in BOOKSHELF:
        print(', '.join(BOOKSHELF[story_to_read]))
    else:
        print(colored('Book not found!', 'red'))

read_fun()
```

Sample output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
storytoread = input(colored("Choose a book to read: ", "yellow"))
for page in storytoread:
    print(page, end='')
```

To:

```
storytoread = input(colored("Choose a book to read: ", "yellow"))
for page in bookshelf[storytoread]:
    print(page, end='')
```

Keep in mind that if the input is not exist as a key in `bookshelf`, you will get `KeyError` exception. To avoid that you can check first if the book exists in the `bookshelf` dict:

```
if storytoread in bookshelf: 
    for page in bookshelf[storytoread]:
        print(page, end='')
else:
    print("Book not found: ", storytoread)
```

Answer (score 0):

your book name is in dictonary so you should have that as a key `bookshelf[book_name]`

```
from termcolor import colored # Ignore this and the "colored" function in the strings, just a 
                               # package I installed.
 titles = ["Dummy Story"] 

 bookshelf = {

 "Dummy Story": ["Page 1", "Page 2", "Page 3", "Page 4"] # The list I want it to print 

  } 


def readfun():

    print(colored("So you want to read a story now?", "green"))
    global titles        
    global bookshelf
    print(titles)
    storytoread = input(colored("Choose a book to read: ", "yellow"))
    for page in bookshelf[storytoread]:
        print(page, end='')


readfun()
```